# How to validate that a user made a selection on a Kendo UI Autocomplete widget?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, autocomplete

I've added a Kendo UI Autocomplete widget to my web app.  Right now, it's bound to a static list of names, but by the time it gets to production, it will need to be able to dynamically fetch names from a data source.

In the data source, each name has an ID, but the user never sees the ID because it's an artificial key.

If the user keys in "Sam H", Kendo might suggest that the user could fill the form with "Sam Harris" or "Sam Houston".  If the user selects one of these, or if she manually keys in one of these two names, then when the form is submitted, the name can be compared to the data source and the ID found. (because ultimately, we want to store the ID of the selected user)

However, I need to handle the case where the user may key in a name that doesn't match anything in the data source.  In this case, the web app should stop the user from submitting the form and advise her to make a valid selection.

How do I do this?

(I am using Kendo UI with AngularJS 1.6)

Comment: We haven't used the Kendo UI controls in a while, so I'm not sure if this is possible, but in general when using an autocomplete although nice text is displayed in the control, the `ng-model` is usually the ID of the selected value (or the object itself). This way if the user does not make a selection, or makes an invalid one, the `ng-model` is not valid and the form cannot be submitted. This is how the `uib-typeahead` directive works.

Comment: I used to do something like that with jQuery UI, but in the examples I've seen with Kendo UI, they just use a list of strings, but their AngularJS documentation is rather sparse.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon have you tried my answer. Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find an example of some binding and how to use it. I found an example on a project I working on.

```
    <input kendo-auto-complete ng-model="country" k-data-source="countryNames" k-options="autocompleteoptions" />

<script>
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
          .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
                        $scope.autocompleteoptions = {
                //dataSource: items,
                //dataTextField: "name",
                //dataValueField: "id",
                //filter: "contains",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (e) {
                  console.log(e);
                    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                    console.log(dataItem);
                }
              }

              $scope.countryNames = [
              "Albania",
              "Andorra",
              "Armenia",
              "Austria",
                  ];
          })
</script>
```

An dojo as example: [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@sehaxx/OJOCITAM)

Here are also some information on Angular JS binding: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#the-k-value-primitive-attribute

Hope this will help you.

Cheers